# File adapter add-on like s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I know this might be an option question but I'm going to ask it anyway.

In the case of an iOS app..

Why would i use a file adapter add-on to my server back end like aws s3 bucket and just list a url in my database instead of just storing files within my database tables?

Ive been reading for hours on this and cant see anything that explains why this should be the case.  There may be a saving in code using a bucket than storing data on a hosted service or there may be a performance issue if the files are constantly being pulled directly from the server?

I cant figure it out and all i can see is dodgy tuts on how to set it up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your question is asking for opinions between two options:

- Storing files in Amazon S3 with a URL to the file stored in a database, or
- Storing files "within my database tables"

Databases are **highly optimized** for storing and retrieving data. They also have the magic of SQL that allows very complex queries to be written in just a few lines. A relational database stores its in rows and columns and creates indexes so that information can be quickly stored, search and retrieved.

Files, on the other hand, are **'blobs' of data** that mean nothing to a database. The are just a sequence of data that it must store somewhere. Databases do not store files very efficiently -- in fact, files are often just stored on the local file system, with a reference to the file stored in the database.

So, it really comes down to storing files in the **most appropriate system**.

**Some of the advantages of storing files in Amazon S3 instead of within a database would be:**

- Replication of the files across three different data centres
- Serving of content via the Internet (via a URL) if security settings permit
- Highly scalable storage (do you wish to scale your database just to serve files?)
- No limit to the amount of data you can store (a database would run out of space when its filesystem fills ups)
- More efficient database backups (because it isn't backing up massive quantities of low-use files)
- Taking advantage of various storage classes, such as Standard-Infrequent Access and Amazon Glacier

**Advantages of storing files in a database:**

- Only one system to store both data and files
- No need to use AWS credentials -- just use the existing SQL credentials
- No need to keep two system synchronized (database and S3 storage)